# ASP.NET MVC: Serve .cshtml files "as is"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Imagine an ASP.NET MVC web application allows a user to browse contents of some VCS repository on the server. Now, this repository, among other things, contains `*.cshtml` files which I would like to render "as is".

In other words, when a user navigates to http://example.com/browse/directory/subdirectory/main.cs , then the "raw" contents of `main.cs` file is displayed - and this is already working fine. However, accessing http://example.com/browse/directory/subdirectory/main.cshtml results in an HttpException deep inside ASP.NET runtime.

I tried removing the `BlockViewHandler` from `/browse` and explicitly allowing `*.cshtml` files in `<requestFiltering>` - but to no avail:

```
  <security>
    <requestFiltering>
      <fileExtensions>
        <remove fileExtension=".cshtml" />
        <remove fileExtension=".vbhtml" />

        <add fileExtension=".cshtml" allowed="true" />
        <add fileExtension=".vbhtml" allowed="true" />
      </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
  </security>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try reading it directly from the file system itself so it bypasses razor. Something like:

```
string filePath = Server.MapPath("~/directory/subdirectory/main.cshtml");
string rawTemplate = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
```

Then stuffing it into a ViewModel or writing directly to the response? You may have to Html.Raw() it to display it so you may want to sanitize the template from XSS stuff if the user can edit it.

Comment: These .cshtml files are not on disk anyway -- they are inside a VCS repository, from which I fish them out programmatically. The culprit here is the URL that ends with ".cshtml", which ASP.NET seems to be choking on.